# Python : redefining the value of a variable by conditions

Tags: python

```
Beta = (math.pi)/2 + (math.pi)/20 - Theta
```

I would love that the variable Beta once calculated receives another value by the following conditions but it seems to have no effect.

```
if Beta < (math.pi)/10:
    Beta == 1

if (math.pi)/10 < Beta < 2*(math.pi)/10:
    Beta == 2

if 2*(math.pi)/10 < Beta < 3*(math.pi)/10:
    Beta == 3 

if (n-1)*(math.pi)/10 < Beta < n*(math.pi)/10:
    Beta == n
```

Comment: You used `=` for the original assignment to `Beta`; why are you using `==` in the others?

Answer (score 1):

You mixed `==` operator with `=`, the first is equality test and the second is assignment operator.
Replace all `==` with `=` and that will work.

Comment: I have a syntax error:                                                                                       for n = 1 to 20:   
    if (n-1) * (math.pi)/10 < Beta < n * (math.pi)/10:
        Beta = n

Comment: It's python, not pascal or whatever language you came from, in for cycle you need to use range's. Like this `for n in range(1, 20): ...`

Comment: θ = arctan(y/x) with y and x negative or positive floating point numbers.  What is the code in Python?

Answer (score 0):

just change the Beta == 1/ Beta == 2/ Beta == 3 / Beta == n

to Beta = 1 , with one equal sign , since double equal sign represent condition and not assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to include `=` sign instead of `==`

`==` sign represents equality check in Python whereas `=` sign is an assignment sign.

Try the following:

```
Beta = (math.pi)/2 + (math.pi)/20 - Theta

if Beta < (math.pi)/10:
    Beta = 1

if (math.pi)/10 < Beta < 2*(math.pi)/10:
    Beta = 2

if 2*(math.pi)/10 < Beta < 3*(math.pi)/10:
    Beta = 3 

if (n-1)*(math.pi)/10 < Beta < n*(math.pi)/10:
    Beta = n
```